# append not appending content but replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jquery `.load` function to load the results from server and append it in my html:

```
$("#content").load('Get/classPosts?class=arts&min=1', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
arr = $.parseJSON(responseText);
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != null) {
        $('#content').append("<section class='contentpost'><div class='contentimg'><a href='" + arr[i][0] + "'><img src='" + arr[i][2] + "'/></a> </div><div class='contenttitle title'><a href='" + arr[i][0] + "'>" + arr[i][1] + "</a></div></section>").slideDown(100);
    }
}
});
```

As far as fetching and appearance of of data through `.load` is concerned its fine, but there are few issues that i am facing with this:

- most important is that it is not actually appending the new data at
  the end of the `#content` but it is just replacing the existing html
  with the new one.
- And before inserting the new data at the top of `#content` there is raw JSON string is being displayed, like this:

  ```
  [
  ["93","Title-1","http://stackoverflow.com"],
  ["92"," Title-2","http://stackoverflow.com"],
  ["90"," Title-3","http://stackoverflow.com"],
  ["89"," Title-4","http://stackoverflow.com"],
  ["89"," Title-5","http://stackoverflow.com"],
  null,null,null,null,null]
  ```

I don't know why it is there on page.

However, this would be a little off question but i would appericiate if somebody can also help me with `.slideDown(100);` function at the end, i want each new content to come out as animated sliding down but its not working also.

thankyou!

Comment: Because you're loading the request into #content (the accepted behavior). You need to use a different AJAX request, perhaps a get() or getJSON()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`load()` does this by default. When you call `load` first, you are telling it to replace the html inside the `#content` div. You need to use `GET` or `POST` to retrieve the information and then append it to `#content`.

Something like this:

```
$.get('Get/classPosts?class=arts&min=1', function (data) {
    if(data.length > 0) {
        arr = $.parseJSON(data);
        var newId;
        for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != null) {
                // unique id for slidedown to work
                newId = $('.contentpost').length;
                $('#content').append("<section id='contentpost-"+newId+"' class='contentpost'><div class='contentimg'><a href='" + arr[i][0] + "'><img src='" + arr[i][2] + "'/></a> </div><div class='contenttitle title'><a href='" + arr[i][0] + "'>" + arr[i][1] + "</a></div></section>");
                // slide down pointing to the newly added contentposts only
                $('#contentpost-'+newId).slideDown(100);
           }
        }
    }
});
```

What you also need to do is set the contentpost class' to hidden in css, something like:

```
.contentpost {
    display:none;
}
```

You need this or the slidedown won't work. The div needs to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks lot, done and working fine. :) .. btw any idea about whats wrong with the `.slideDown(100);` function?

Comment: Yea, I'll change the code above now, to show you, and explain it